# How to install xargs in container running openjdk:17-oracle

Tags: java, containers, oracle-linux

I'm trying to install xargs in a container running openjdk:17-oracle, but I'm unable to figure our what package manager is present in this image.

```
FROM openjdk:17-oracle
RUN apt-get install findutils
```

Throws error:

```
 => ERROR [stage-1 4/4] RUN apt-get install findutils                                                                      0.5s
------
 > [stage-1 4/4] RUN apt-get install findutils:
#13 0.395 /bin/sh: apt-get: command not found
-
```

As does `yum install findutils`, and several others.

I required xargs as this is used by the gradle runner to build the 'execute' command for my java process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not really documented, but I found [this in the issue tracker of the Oracle images](https://github.com/oracle/container-images/issues/24) for the Oracle Linux based images:

```
RUN microdnf install findutils
```

For the Alpine based images the command would be:

```
RUN apk update && apk add findutils
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly! Not sure how I managed to try so many but skip over the microdnf option. I had tried alpine but got jvm/runtime crashes mysteriously so reverted back to the oracle one.

Answer (score 2):

To answer this, you first need to find out what sort of base OS environment (if any) this container is based on.

One reasonably easy way is to 'inspect' the image. You can do this using Docker Desktop, or the 'docker inspect' command.

[image: Inspecting image layers in Docker Desktop]

In this case, we can see 'microdnf' being used to install a package. 'microdnf' is a slimmed-down version of 'dnf' (modern replacement for 'yum'). Perhaps this image is based on the likes of a 'ubi' image (cut-down redistributable subset of Red Hat)...

You can also then start up the container and experiment. I've specified a different entry-point, because otherwise you get a jshell, which is not particularly useful for looking at how the image is built.

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash openjdk:17-oracle
```

Knowing that 'microdnf' is the tool you'll be wanting; you can just use make a derivative container with the following in a new layer.

```
microdnf install findutils
```

Trust that helps.

Comment: Or you can read the documentation. Most images state what image they are based on in the README.

Comment: I was unable to find the documentation for this. All I found was that it existed and had a few aliases.